# how to get or observe livedata in room database class

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I have created an entity along with corresponding dao. In dao class, i have a following method:

```
@Query("select * from Book")
LiveData<List<Book>> getAll();
```

I have observed this live data in activities and fragments. Now i wanted to get the **book list** when database opened its connection. I want this operation inside room database class. Actually inside onOpen() method.

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
...
    public static synchronized AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
...
    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new 
        RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            // get book list information and do some task
        }
    };
}
```

I am following the android mvvm architecture pattern. I have some questions at this point. Is it possible to get the value or observe the livedata(book) inside onOpen() method?. I know I could do this by writing another method in dao class which doesn't return livedata, but will it be a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the liveData by calling the dao.getAll(). But in general it's not recommended. You will be getting the liveData from the model. Check out this sample for recommended way of handling the data and the use of liveData. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample

Comment: Basically, I want to get the list from that livedata. So, how will i get that list. However, i think i need to call dao.getAll().getValue() to get the list, but it returns null. In that case, I have to observe that data. If i observe than how will i get lifecycleowner?

Comment: You're not supposed to do any work from `onOpen` callback. You need to observe the liveData in your view and based on the data being null or not, you ask ViewModel to do some work which in turn does some operation on your DB.